# Authenticating using OfficeDev/office-js-helpers rather than adal

Tags: javascript, adal, office-addins, office-js, adal.js

I'm working on an Office Add-in that currently uses adal to obtain an auth token.

As I want to use the Fabric front end I am changing it to React and I notice that the officer-js-helpers have implemented authenticators that seem to do the same job as the adal library.
 Am I correct in this assumption? If so, how do I duplicate this adal config using the office-js-helpers authentication functions:

```
var adalConfig = {
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    tenant: 'myprivatesite.onmicrosoft.com',
    clientId: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx',
    endpoints: {
      'https://my.private.url.endpoint/path': 'https://myprivatesite.onmicrosoft.com/path.to.something',
    }
```

And this token request:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);
 authContext.acquireToken('https://myprivatesite.onmicrosoft.com/path.to.something', function (error, token) {
        console.log(token)
      });
```

**UPDATE**:
I have got the `adal.js` library working in my react app. I have used some of the code from the `init` function in the `adalAuthenticationService` angular provider to retrieve the authentication token.

So the question remains. Can I use the `office-js-helpers` to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK It appears it is extremely easy. All that is required from the adal configuration is the client Id and the tenant.

```
if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) {
  return;
}

var authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();

authenticator.endpoints.registerAzureADAuth('xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx', //clientId
'myprivatesite.onmicrosoft.com' // tenant
);

authenticator.authenticate(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.AzureAD)
  .then(function (token) {
    console.log(token);
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: The question is misleading, you were looking for a working code for Office-js-helpers work. It is not a comparison of adal.js and office.js helpers. Actually this question has nothing to do with adal.js.

Answer (score 2):

Adal.js cannot be used out of the box for web add-ins authentication because within the sandboxed iFrame context of a web add-ins you cannot navigate simply to the authentication login page hosted outside your domain.

Office-js-helpers uses the [dialogAPI](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/officeui.md) when available and a popup as a fallback solution when not available.

If I remember correctly Office-js-helpers targets only Azure AD v2.0 (which comes with a lot of nice new features comparing to Azure AD). I guess it is a good choice.

I created an [Open source sample](https://github.com/Keluro/Office365-AddinWeb-SignInSample) the documentation can be interesting to you. However, this is not exactly what you want it is based on an AuthorizationCode flow while you are looking for Implicit flow.

Comment: I'm not concerned about that aspect - I have an add-in that currently works and uses the existing office authentication to authenticate the add-in. In effect, if you have already authenticated with outlook.office.com (in my case), then the add-in will launch correctly. I'd like to know if the office-js-helpers are appropriate in this context and if indeed it is possible to use them in the way I have.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You said that you are already authenticated within Outlook but where do you get the bearer for requesting AzureAD APIs? There must be a second authentication flow to retrieve the bearer token (which was performed by adal.js). Office-js-helpers will help you implementing the OAUTH flow in an addin context without hitting the iFrame/popup problem. You will have to reimplement things that were handled by adal.js like refresh_tokens etc.

Comment: Even if you did not have the iFrame/popup crisis yet when implementing your flow it is because you probably set `login.windows.net` as a trusted appdomain in your manifest which allowed the redirection in the addin. However, in some cases the login page is a `company page` and you cannot know its domain by advance and set it in your manifest. See this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/08/10/connecting-to-office-365-from-an-office-add-in/). Now with the dialogAPI (used by Office-js-helpers) the popup can be avoided in most cases.

Comment: I think you are right about having a trusted domain in the manifest, however I don't have any visibility of that (I'm only doing the front-end). The existing add-in uses the adal-angular.js which has a provider with an init function that retrieves user credentials and returns them to the add-in, then the token can be retrieved. I am looking for the documentation that shows me how to use office-js-helpers to achieve the same ends. This https://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-office-365-web-applications-react/ shows how to get adal.js working, but I'd prefer to use the office-js-helpers.

Comment: I had problems with adal.js and office-js runtime https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/129#issuecomment-132326840 but the ADAL guys just add a support for popup based. But you would prefer relying when possible on the dialogAPI (release mid 2016). No perfect solution here...

Comment: OK thanks for your time - I'm going to hack out the contents of the adal-angular.js into some useable code.

Comment: You are welcome, consider upvoting or accepting answer if it helped you. Happy coding.