# X-Frame-Option DENY error when AAD sign-in in office add-in

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, office-addins, office-js, adal.js

I'm working on build Office add-in with Adal.js for AAD integration. And my add-in requires some permissions.

When I open add-in in OneNote and try to call login from adal.js, it request login.microsoftonline.com and gives X-Frame-Option Deny error.
I think it's because office add-in running in iFrame, how can I workaround this?

```
login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&cl…nt-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.13&nonce=ced03385-f1ca-4206-bb23-6c3e8338a0d2:1 Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_…ient-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.13&nonce=ced03385-f1ca-4206-bb23-6c3e8338a0d2' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Authenticating with OAUTH flow within an office web add-ins is a known issue.The better explanation of the problem can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/08/10/connecting-to-office-365-from-an-office-add-in/).

> Due to the popularity of clickjacking on the internet, it is common to
>   prevent login pages from being display inside frames. The
>   X-FRAME-Options meta tag in HTML makes it easy for providers to
>   implement this safeguard on a widespread or domain/origin-specific
>   basis. Pages that are not “frameable” will not load consistently in an
>   Office add-in

Therefore you need to rely on a popup mechanism. In one word, the authentication flow will be made on a popup to avoid iFraming problems.

The link above is a little bit outdated because it states that popup is a necessary evil. Microsoft awares of this problem proposed recently the [dialogAPI](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/officeui.md) to overcome this problem.

Let us get back to our Adal.js problem. I believe that you should stop using adal.js because it was not meant to be used in our add-in web context. Even if they [implemented a popup technique](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/129#issuecomment-132326840). They do not use the dialogAPI when available.

You should try to take benefit of this dialogAPI when available otherwise you will hit many problems (deactivated popup, security regions etc.).

Your best option is to implement your own flow mechanism or use [Office-js-helpers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers) as explained in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674084/authenticating-using-officedev-office-js-helpers-rather-than-adal/40675000#40675000)

Comment: Note that the DialogAPI is not yet available for Outlook Online or any version of OWA.

Comment: @lgaud good point ! you need to check the availability of  dialogApi and implement a fallback relying in popup. Check this sample I wrote for more information on the subject https://github.com/Keluro/Office365-AddinWeb-SignInSample

Comment: Important update: DialogAPI is supported by all modern MS Office versions. See [Dialog API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/dialog-api-requirement-sets?view=office-js)